# How do I sort/recover deleted items on Mac?

Tags: itunes, macos, recovery, trash, sort

So I'm a DJ and I was going through my music files in Itunes when I made a bonehead mistake of deleting about half of my music library! Now I go to my Trash Bin in hopes of being able to recover those files that I deleted, however I am unable to sort through the files by "Date Added" in the trash bin. When I select "Date Added" as a column, all of the dates show "--". If I have dates, I can look at everything I deleted when I made my mistake, and simply "put back" all those items. However, my trash bin is not showing me any dates in this field! Is there any way to bring dates into the "Date Added" column, or if there is any other way to sort through my trash bin to recover those files into iTunes?

FYI: I currently use OS Mavericks

Thanks!

Comment: Why don't you just take all audio files out of the Trash and re-import them into iTunes?

Comment: I could, however, my Trash is pretty packed and there's a lot of stuff in there I don't want to re-import

Answer (score 1):

If you are not afraid of the Terminal.app try starting the Terminal.app and enter the following commands:

```
cd ~/.Trash
ls -lu
```

This may result in something like:

```
-rwxr-xr-x  1 otto  staff  700416 Jan 26 23:33 MyRemovedFile.txt
```

where 23:33 is the value which should show up in the 'Date Added' column in Finder.
Could not test this with iTunes, but hope it may give some clues for trying to solve your issue.

Comment: Add the option `-t` to sort by last modified date (`-tr` to reverse it)

Comment: not for nothing but digging through the trash is better than using a commercial file recovery tool or sending the drive off to a data recovery $peciali$t. Recover all the files from the trash and then sort by kind, that will group most, if not all your music files

Answer (score 1):

Too late now, but for future reference, Finder has an 'Undo' feature just like most other apps.

Cmd/z will undo your last action, even if you accidentally trashed a thousand items in one go.